# PHP multi-step form with neo4j

Tags: php, ajax, database, forms, neo4j

I am making multi step form for submission of a company information in PHP with neo4j graph database. In first step there is a submission of basic information and in second step , some advanced information for a user to fill.

Then problem is that when I am creating a company node in the first step of the form, it is created successfully but in the next step I am unable to get company id to store Step 2 information of this company. The step 2 form resides in another file.

I am using AJAX form submit method.

I basically need the company name or id that is generated in the first step, in the second step form to store step 2 information of the company.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some code could only be helpful for us.

However, if you what you want to achieve is close to the lastInsertId in PDO/Mysql for e.g., you can achieve it with neo4j too with the RETURN statement that will return you the created node and you can get the id from it, pass it to the second step of your form and retrieve the node with the passed id.

The following code is an example using the PHP Client from Neoxygen https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient :

```
// Creating your company node
$q = 'CREATE (c:Company {name:"My Awesome Company"}) RETURN c';
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($q);

$id = $result->getSingleNode()->getId();
```

Pass now the id to the next step of your form, and load the company from the id :

```
$id = $_SERVER['POST']['id'];
$q = 'MATCH (c:Company) WHERE id(c) = {company_id} RETURN c';
$params = array('company_id' => $id);
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($q, $params);

$company = $result->getSingleNode();
// Want to get some info of the node ?
$companyName = $company->getProperty('name');
```

Hope it helped.

Chris